# Compute $\lim_{x \rightarrow 4} \frac{(2x^2 - 7x -4)}{(-x^2 + 8x - 16)}$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I'm trying compute $\lim_{x \rightarrow 4} \frac{(2x^2 - 7x -4)}{(-x^2 + 8x - 16)}$ without L'Hopital's rule.

> $\textbf{My attempt:}$
>
> $\lim_{x \rightarrow 4} \frac{(2x^2 - 7x -4)}{(-x^2 + 8x - 16)} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 4} \frac{2(x + \frac{1}{2})(x - 4)}{(-1)(x - 4)^2} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 4} \frac{2(x + \frac{1}{2})}{(-1)(x - 4)}$

I'm stuck here. How can I eliminate $x- 4$ to compute the limit? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I believe your $(x-\frac{1}{2})$ should read $(x+\frac{1}{2})$. Btw, you haven't used L'Hopital's rule although this is also valid. Basically, the top(numerator) tends to a finite number, the bottom(denominator) tends to zero, so it diverges.

Comment: @daruma, I corrected, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you did is correct, and it prove that the limit doesn't exist in $4$, since you get $+\infty $ in $4^-$ and $-\infty $ in $4^+$.

Comment: I understood, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The factors are not correct.
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 4^{+}}\dfrac{2x^{2}-7x-4}{-x^{2}+8x-16}&=\lim_{x\rightarrow 4^{+}}\dfrac{(2x+1)(x-4)}{-(x-4)^{2}}\\
&=\lim_{x\rightarrow 4^{+}}\dfrac{2x+1}{-(x-4)}\\
&=-\infty.
\end{align*}

And so the limit is $\infty$ for $y\rightarrow 4^{-}$, as @Cameron Williams has pointed out, the limit does not exist even in the extended real sense.

Comment: Your conclusion is not correct. The limit does not exist even in the extended sense.

Answer (score 1):

Your question of the limit

$$\lim _{x\to \:4+}\left(\frac{2x^2-7x-4}{-x^2+8x-16}\right)=+\infty$$
In fact:

$$\lim _{x\to \:4+}\left(\frac{2x^2-7x-4}{-x^2+8x-16}\right)=\lim _{x\to \:4+}\left(-\frac{2x+1}{x-4}\right)=$$
$$=-\lim _{x\to \:4+}\left(2x+1\right)\cdot \lim \:_{x\to \:4+}\left(\frac{1}{x-4}\right)=-9\cdot \infty =-\infty$$
(with numerator/denominator in the 2nd step).

After

$$\lim _{x\to \:4-}\left(\frac{2x^2-7x-4}{-x^2+8x-16}\right)=+\infty$$
With same steps you have

$$-\lim _{x\to \:4-}\left(2x+1\right)=-9$$
and 
$$\lim _{x\to \:4-}\left(\frac{1}{x-4}\right)=-\infty$$

Hence

$$\lim _{x\to \:4+}\left(\frac{2x^2-7x-4}{-x^2+8x-16}\right)=-9\cdot (-\infty)=+\infty$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that the limit doesn't exist, indeed as an alternative let $x=y+4$ with $y\to 0$ then

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 4} \frac{(2x^2 - 7x -4)}{(-x^2 + 8x - 16)}=\lim_{y \rightarrow 0} \frac{(2(y+4)^2 - 7(y+4) -4)}{(-(y+4)^2 + 8(y+4) - 16)}
=\lim_{y \rightarrow 0} \frac{2y^2+9y}{-y^2}=\lim_{y \rightarrow 0} \frac{2y+9}{-y}$$

thus the limit doesn't exist since $\lim_{y \rightarrow 0^+}\neq\lim_{y \rightarrow 0^-}$.